# Xubuntu login loop

Tags: command-line, permissions, xubuntu, login

I'm running Xubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (trusty).

When I try to login as my main user account I get a black screen for a second, then back to the login screen. I can, however, login as a guest user. I tried separately `chown`ing and deleting `~/.Xauthority` as this has been a problem for other people, but this did not help.

If I login using the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and try to run some commands (i.e. `ls`, `clear`, `grep`), I get the following error for each command:

```
-bash: /home/cameron/bin/ls: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Using `/bin/ls` or `/usr/bin/clear` works however, as does using `sudo`.

This is the output of `/bin/cat ~/.xsession-errors`:

```
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 33: /home/cameron/bin/cat: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 34: /home/cameron/bin/truncate: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 106: /home/cameron/bin/ls: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
/home/cameron/bin/id: 1: /home/cameron/bin/id: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
/home/cameron/bin/cat: 1: /home/cameron/bin/cat: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
Could not find dbus-launch; Xfce will not work properly

(xfsettingsd:4321): xfsettingsd-ERROR **: Failed to connect to the dbus session bus.

(xfwm4:4322): xfwm4-CRITICAL **: Xfconf could not be initialized

(xfwm4:4322): xfwm4-WARNING **: Missing data from default files
/home/cameron/bin/grep: 1: /home/cameron/bin/grep: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
/home/cameron/bin/grep: 1: /home/cameron/bin/grep: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
/home/cameron/bin/grep: 1: /home/cameron/bin/grep: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
/home/cameron/bin/grep: 1: /home/cameron/bin/grep: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
/home/cameron/bin/grep: 1: /home/cameron/bin/grep: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
/home/cameron/bin/cut: 1: /home/cameron/bin/cut: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
/home/cameron/bin/grep: 1: /home/cameron/bin/grep: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
/home/cameron/bin/cut: 1: /home/cameron/bin/cut: Syntax error: word  unexpected (expecting ")")
/home/cameron/bin/grep: 1: /home/cameron/bin/grep: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
/home/cameron/bin/grep: 1: /home/cameron/bin/grep: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
/home/cameron/bin/grep: 1: /home/cameron/bin/grep: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
/home/cameron/bin/grep: 1: /home/cameron/bin/grep: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
/home/cameron/bin/cut: 1: /home/cameron/bin/cut: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
/home/cameron/bin/grep: 1: /home/cameron/bin/grep: Syntax error: word  unexpected (expecting ")")
/home/cameron/bin/grep: 1: /home/cameron/bin/grep: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
/home/cameron/bin/cut: 1: /home/cameron/bin/cut: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
/home/cameron/bin/grep: 1: /home/cameron/bin/grep: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
/home/cameron/bin/grep: 1: /home/cameron/bin/grep: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
/home/cameron/bin/grep: 1: /home/cameron/bin/grep: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
/home/cameron/bin/grep: 1: /home/cameron/bin/grep: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
/home/cameron/bin/grep: 1: /home/cameron/bin/grep: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
/home/cameron/bin/cut: 1: /home/cameron/bin/cut: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
/home/cameron/bin/grep: 1: /home/cameron/bin/grep: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
/home/cameron/bin/cut: 1: /home/cameron/bin/cut: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
/home/cameron/bin/which: 1: /home/cameron/bin/which: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
** Message: First Orage start. Searching default timezone.
** Message: Default timezone set to Europe/London.
** Message: Orage **: 15:44:42  wakeup timer init 0
xfdesktop: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
orage: Fatal IO error 0 (Success) on X server :1.
```

EDIT:

```
$ echo "$PATH"
home/cameron/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/cameron/.composer/vendor/bin

$ command -v cat
/home/cameron/bin/cat

$ file $(command -v cat)
-bash: /home/cameron/bin/file: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

$ /bin/file $(command -v cat)
/home/cameron/bin/cat: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=b282331acc5bb5f24ebb96445de7695e6d94d0c2, stripped

$ /bin/uname -a
Linux moon-unit 3.13.0-63-generic #103-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 14 21:42:59 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: How come you apparently have executable files named `grep`, `cut` and so on in your `/home/cameron/bin/` directory? (Based on the error messages it looks like they might all be scripts rather than binary executables.)

Comment: No idea. I'm relatively new to linux so I'm not really sure what half of those error messages are referring to

Comment: What's the output of `echo "$PATH"`, `command -v cat`, `file "$(command -v cat)"` and `uname -a`? Please [edit] your question, if you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you extracted an ARM root file system in your home directory. You getting all those errors because `~/bin` is searched first whenever you try to run something, then instead of run the distribution's binaries in `/bin` your system is trying to run the foreign binaries in `~/bin`.

Try to rename the `~/bin` directory:

```
cd /home/cameron
/bin/mv bin bin.bkp
```

Comment: I extracted a Raspberry Pi iso in /home/cameron recently so that must have been the problem, I won't be doing that again. Thanks for your help!